# TikZ in ConTeXt: How to flush left align a node with changed font size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

Consider the following MWE:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture
    \node[draw,font=\big,text width=4.75cm,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};
\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

As included within the node's text I do not expect the text to hyphenate. But that is what I get (with ConTeXt from TL2018 and current beta):

[image: hyphenation]

Just for comparison: A similar LaTeX document will not reproduce that strange behavior (i.e. the `flush left` option actually does what it says).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw,text width=4.75cm,font=\large,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As I had some issues with ConTeXt and text alignment in the past, my question is: Is this kind of behavior to be expected? And how to actually flush left align a node in TikZ in ConTeXt?

Comment: In ConteXt, `leftflushed` does not automatically imply `nothypehnated`. I don't know how tikz maps node options to low level directives

Comment: @Aditya Thanks, then this is a bug in TikZ because the manual states that `flush left` will suppress hyphenation. Actually, that also answers my question, so feel free to write up an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `font=\big`.  The macro `\big` is a math command to choose a different delimiter size, not a font command.  Unfortunately, when using `\big` in ConTeXt without a delimiter, it will just silently swallow the following token.  However, if you try the following example in Plain TeX, it will get noisy.

```
\input tikz
\tikz \node[draw,font=\big,text width=4.75cm,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};
\bye
```

```
! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
\rightskip 
\pgfutil@raggedright ->\rightskip 
                                  \z@ plus2em \spaceskip .3333em \xspaceskip...
```

So to rectify this problem, just remove `font=\big` or replace it with `\tfa` or `\switchtobodyfont[big]` or something similar.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\tikz \node[draw,text width=4.75cm,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};
\stoptext
```

[image]

But what is this?  It looks a bit more ragged but why is it still hypenated?  This is because the `flush left` and `flush right` option use these macros from `pgfutil-common.tex`:

```
% Ragged left and ragged right

\def\pgfutil@raggedright{\rightskip\z@ plus2em \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\relax}
\def\pgfutil@raggedleft{\leftskip\z@ plus2em \rightskip\z@ \spaceskip.3333em \xspaceskip.5em\parfillskip0pt\relax}
```

These are the definitions of `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` from Plain TeX.  These are by far not as ragged as the LaTeX version, where the margin skip is set to `0pt plus 1fil`.  So to emulate the LaTeX raggedness, you have to redefine `\pgfutil@raggedright`.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\unprotect
\def\pgfutil@raggedright
  {\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil
   \leftskip=0pt
   \parindent=0pt
   \relax}
\protect
\starttext
\tikz \node[draw,text width=4.75cm,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};
\stoptext
```

[image]

---

*N.B.:* ConTeXt's `\raggedright` is also not very ragged.  It sets stretch of `\rightskip` only to [twice the body font size](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/3861c9ef2ffeffe824f05a255534d61800e27e7a/tex/context/base/mkiv/spac-ali.mkiv#L213), i.e. `\rightskip=0pt plus 24pt` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Obviously one should not believe the TikZ manual when it comes to ConTeXt…

Comment: @TeXnician Can you elaborate?  I checked the manual for `font=\big` but could not find anything.

Comment: No, I mean for `align=flush left` where it explicitly says that hyphenation will be suppressed.

Answer (score 3):

Henri has beautifully debugged the problem, but let me propose an alternative solution. When using TikZ in ConTeXt, I *always* use ConTeXt macros to handle text formatting:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\starttext
\starttikzpicture
    \node[draw,font=\big,text width=4.75cm,align=flush left] {This text should not hyphenate.};

    \node at (0, -2cm) 
        {\framed[ width=4.75cm, align={flushleft}]
            {This text does not hyphenate}};

    \node at (0, -4cm) 
        {\framed[ width=4.75cm, align={flushleft,nothyphenated}]
            {This text does not hyphenate}};

    % The result that you wanted:
    \node at (0, -6cm) 
        {\framed[foregroundstyle={\switchtobodyfont[big]}, width=4.75cm, align={flushleft,nothyphenated}]
            {This text does not hyphenate}};

\stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

You can add the right value to `offset` key of `\framed` to get the same offset as TikZ.